# Selecting li from unordered list using ul and li id's

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'd like to obtain a li item from an unordered list using the id attribute of both elements as part of the selector.

This is an example of how I made it work using the ul css class:

```
var listItem = $('ul.selectedItems li#' + opt.list[i].ID);
```

I tried to use the following approach with no luck:

```
var listItem = $("#" + opt.name).childs.find("#" + opt.list[i].ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var listItem = $('#' + opt.name + ' > li#' + opt.list[i].ID);
```

which should select `li` elements that are children of the first.

See the documentation here: [jQuery Selectors: Parent/Child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild).

Comment: I tried that way without any luck, but $('#' + opt.name + ' > li[id$=' + opt.list[i].ID + ']') did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be any need for a complex selector/lookup when you're using IDs. **Element IDs should be unique across the entire document**, so finding an element is as simple as

```
var listItem = $("#" + opt.list[i].ID);
```

If that doesn't work I suggest fixing up your IDs so they are unique rather than working around the problem with an unnecessarily complex CSS selector.

Comment: +1 -- and I'd try to give you +2 if you'd boldface "Element IDs should be unique"

Comment: In a perfect world where you don't work on others code: You are right. BUT, I'm working on code emulating a server side combobox using an unordered list. The list elements get generated dinamically from a datasource, therefore the ul output will be always the same when two server controls have the same datasource.

I can control the ul id but not the one from it's li elements. Since selections should be control independent I need to be able to use this complex selector.